# People with similar traits

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-requests, vocabulary, word-usage

I am curious as to whether there is a noun or some other, more suitable expression for that group of people which shares my personality type. I often use 'people with same traits or personality'.

Comment: When you say 'mates', do you mean 'sexual partners', or simply 'close friends' (as in the colloquial British English / Australian term, e.g. "I spent last night with my mates down the pub")?

Comment: If you mean people who share your personality type but with whom you don't necessarily socialize [after all, a group of mates may well have very different personalities], perhaps the modern use of 'tribe' is closer.  But that does also imply a lifestyle choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more general than personality type but it fits somewhat:

***Kindred*** souls.

Answer (score 0):

"Birds of a feather (flock together)"

Answer (score -1):

possibly clique or coterie

I can't comment so I have to write it in an answer

Answer (score -1):

The best word I can think of is *peers*.

> - one that is of equal standing with another :  one belonging to the same societal group especially based on age, grade, or status
> - a person who is equal to another in abilities, qualifications, age, background, and social status

*Peers* could refer to anyone who shares your personality or otherwise "belongs to the same group", regardless whether they are actual acquaintances of yours.